# Android OpenGL ES texture TextImage2D error

Tags: android, opengl-es, bitmap, textures

Due to some unfathomable reason, the textures won't load.

Here's the method

```
     public static void loadGLTexture(GL10 gl, Context context){

     BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
     options.inDensity = 240;// needed so that the image will be 512x512

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.glasstexture, options); 
    int width = bitmap.getWidth();
    int height = bitmap.getHeight();

    Log.i("GridLoginSquare.loadGLTexture 96", "Bitmap:{w:" + width + " h:" + height + "}");

    gl.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
    gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

    // create nearest filtered texture
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
    gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);

    // Use Android GLUtils to specify a two-dimensional texture image from our bitmap
    GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);  //error is on this line

    Log.e("GridLoginSquare.loadGLTexture 102", " ERR "+gl.glGetError()); 
    // Clean up

    bitmap.recycle();           
}
```

The size of my texture image is 405 x 512

The line `Log.e("GridLoginSquare.loadGLTexture 102", " ERR "+gl.glGetError());` gives
me a 1281 error which (after investigating others who had similar problems) means
`INVALID_VALUE`

The above code is a part of the overall `GridLoginSquare` class which is [here](https://gist.github.com/f1d98be8ce8345674519)

**NOTE** This problem had already persisted before `BitmapFactory.Options` density was included to scale the image. Similarly the texture uv was divided by 405 and 512 when this was included in the gist code.

Answer (score 2):

I have had this problem when I did not put my textures in the drawable-nodpi folder. Try moving your textures into that folder.

Also, OpenGL prefers your textures to have dimensions that are powers of two. I am not sure if this would cause the textures to not appear at all, but you may as well try making your texture images 512x512 or 256x256 just to see.

Comment: I did scale my image by 512 x 512..It doesn't work. Also I don't see `no-dpi` drawable folders. Only `hdpi, mdpi, lodpi`

Comment: Create your own drawable folder and call it drawable-nodpi. Place your textures in there and let me know if it works.

Comment: Try making the actual images 512x51 and using `options.inScaled=false` instead of `inDensity`. I've never gotten a density-scaled bitmap to load in OpenGLES correctly.

Comment: moving the image to drawable-xxhdip solved the issue

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same error at textImage2D with glGetError returning 0, and WindyB's solution of using images whose width & length are powers of two... DID WORK form me! Thank you very much! :)

This error took place only in Android 2 (exactly Android 2.3.3). In Android 4 it always worked fine (I like to test my Apps in different Android versions).

By the way, I had no need of creating folder 'drawable-nodpi', I have it all stacked in just 'drawable'

In case it helps: At http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/opengl.html#manifest under 'Declaring OpenGL Requirements' it says that some texture compression formats are not compatible with some devices.. Maybe your problem has something to do with this?

Comment: PD: Sorry WindyB but I am not allowed to vote up your answer cos I'm new at stack Overflow :(

Comment: And... It doesn't work in my Samsung Galaxy S SCL :( The virtual device in which it worked was different, a Nexus S, maybe it has something to do with my device's texture managing capabilities... I'll try to investigate further... :(

Answer (score 0):

I have my textures on drawable-nodpi folder (which we have to create) and was getting the same error 1281 after call this function: **GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bmp, 0);**
And it was being caused because **my textures wasn't at power of 2**, so after I fix it (leave it at power of 2), it works fine, only leaving a texture bleeding (when a tiny undesired part of the texture appears on the borders), but this is solved adjusting the values of the uvs coordinates.